# Duplicate error messages when posting answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, posting

If the user inserts in his answer a link to jsfiddle (for example: `http://jsfiddle.net/asd123`) without providing some code, the following error is thrown:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

That's OK.

The problem is when the user insert more than one link to jsfiddle, without providing some code. Suppose that he insert 3 links. **Three duplicate errors will be thrown.**

See the following screen shot.

> [image]

If the user will insert *n* links to jsfiddle, *n* errors will be shown.

> [image]

Comment: It is 3 times as bad though... maybe they'll understand the seriousness of the situation :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now. Error messages are now de-duped prior to display.